# Expresso Store - Exclude Product from Order Quantity

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

I'm using Expresso-Store to process product orders for a non-profit. In addition to selling a range of handmade products we are offering visitors an option to donate.

I have most of the donation stuff working just fine. I used Justin Long's advice posted here: http://iamjustinlong.com/blog/single/accepting_donations_with_expresso_store/

As suggested I have created a channel for all the products and then a separate channel which holds a single "Donation" product with a cost of $1.00. The visitor adjusts the quantity of this item which results in a donation amount of $1.00 * qty.

The specific problem I'm running into is displaying the total quantity of items in the cart when there's also a "Donation" product added. Since the donation amount is determined by quantity * $1.00 but in reality it represents a single donation, my {order_qty} is way off since it includes the many multiples of Donation products.

I have a small cart icon that is displaying a number above and next to it with the {order_qty} but I need to **exclude** the donation product from this calculation. How might I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly difficult to do using the current version. The best I can suggest is not to display the {order_qty} on your checkout page (most sites only display the total anyway).

However, in saying that, the next version of Store has first-class donations support, so it will soon be possible.